# How to close this modal

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-modal

I am unable to close this modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<button class="open-button" data-toggle="modal" Text="Open Form" onclick="openForm()">Open Form</button>
<div class="form-popup" id="videobox" style="display:none;">
    <video id="myVideo" controls autoplay width="300" height="300" >
        <source src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/videos/VID-20191125-WA0059.mp4'); ?>" type="video/mp4">
            Sorry, your browser doesn't support the video element.
    </video>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `data-dismiss` should work.

Comment: You have add `class='modal' ` as well into the #videobox div . But if you dont want to add modal class you have to write custom event click `$("#videobox ").modal("hide")` on the Close button

Answer (score 2):

Modify Your HTML code as below

```
<!-- Modal -->
 <button class="open-button" data-toggle="modal" Text="Open Form" 
  onclick="openForm()">Open Form</button>
 <div class="form-popup" id="videobox" style="display:none;">
    <video id="myVideo" controls autoplay width="300" height="300" >
      <source src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/videos/VID-20191125- WA0059.mp4'); ?>" 
        type="video/mp4">
        Sorry, your browser doesn't support the video element.
    </video>
 <button type="button" id="btnClosePopup" class="btn btn-primary" data- 
     dismiss="modal">Close</button>
 </div>
```

And Put this javascrip code to your Source code

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      $("#btnClosePopup").click(function () {
        $("#videobox").modal("hide");
       });
    });
  </script>
```